# Lucene 5.5.4, NumericRangeQuery : How to search by non range values, for example by array of ints

Tags: java, arrays, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am new to Lucene and looking for help.

Here is that I have

```
/**
 * JPA Persistence Unit.
 */
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

/**
 * Hibernate Full Text Entity Manager.
 */

private FullTextEntityManager ftem;

@PostConstruct
@Async
public void intializeIndexes() throws InterruptedException {
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =
        Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
    fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
}

protected FullTextEntityManager getFullTextEntityManager() {
    ftem = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
    return ftem;
```

### }

body of search method

```
QueryBuilder qb = getFullTextEntityManager().getSearchFactory()
                                                .buildQueryBuilder()
                                                .forEntity(AmazonProduct.class)
                                                .get();

    BooleanJunction junction = qb.bool();

if(request.getMinPrice() != null || request.getMaxPrice() != null) {
        junction.must(NumericRangeQuery.newDoubleRange(PRICE_FIELD, request.getMinPrice(), request.getMaxPrice(), true, true));
    }

    if(request.getMinWeight() != null || request.getMaxWeight() != null) {
        junction.must(NumericRangeQuery.newDoubleRange(WEIGHT_FIELD, request.getMinWeight(), request.getMaxWeight(), true, true));
    }

    if (null != request.getProductTiers() && request.getProductTiers().length > 0) {
        for (int tier : request.getProductTiers()) {
            junction.must(NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("productTier", tier, tier, true, true));
        }
```

It's ok when I complete range search by price, by weight.

But I don't know how to search by tears, where tears is the array of ints like [1, 3, 5, 7], so I don't need the ranges here. I only need object where tears should be 1, 3, 5 or 7. I have column in database "tier" of int. So how should I organize the query? Do I need NumericRangeQuery here? 
Huge Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem by using boolean subquery

```
if (request.getProductTiers() != null && request.getProductTiers().length > 0) {
        BooleanJunction tierQuery = qb.bool();
        for (int tier : request.getProductTiers()) {
            tierQuery.should(NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange(PROD_TIER_KEY, tier, tier, true, true));
        }
        junction.must(tierQuery.createQuery());
    }
```

I have tried different queries but this one works

subquery works like this

```
+productCategory:Home~2 +(productTier:[3 TO 3] productTier:[6 TO 6])
```

There is subquery with OR condition inside the brackets